# Organizing databases and tables in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have 2 servers, on one server the *access6_identical* sql file is on the second directory under *identical* as can be seen here:

[image: Capture 1]

On the other server, it is on the parent directory as can be seen here:

[image: Capture 2]

1. How do I set it so that it is in the secondary directory as shown in the first example?
2. Does this make any difference when linked to the SQL files, from e.g. Wordpress config?
3. Why is it then when I need to import the SQL file, I must create an empty table with a meaningless value, then I'm able to import the SQL file onto the server?